# Simple Linq to XML Query Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, xml, linq, select, where-clause

I nominate me for village idiot.

Why doesn't this work:

```
foreach (XElement clientField in _clientXml.Descendants("row").Descendants())
{
    var newFieldName =
        from sourceField in _sourceEntries.Descendants("Field")
        where (string)sourceField.Attribute("n") == (string)clientField.Attribute("n")
        select new
            {
                FieldName = ((string) sourceField.Attribute("n")),
                AcordRef = ((string) sourceField.Attribute("m"))
             };
        foreach (var element in newFieldName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Field Name: {0}", 
            element.FieldName, element.AcordRef);
        }
}
```

My source XML files are loaded with XElement.Load(myFileName). In debug, clientField has an attribute n="Policy Number". The first element of _sourceEntries.Descendants("Field") also has an attribute n="Policy Number". Indeed, each element in _clientXml.Descendants("row").Descendants() has a matching row in _sourceEntries.Descendants("Field"). And, I know just enough to know that the select is lazy, so in debug I look at the Console.WriteLine block. No matter what I've tried, newFieldName is an empty set.

Just in case, here's the first element of the client file:

```
<Column_0 n="Policy Number">ABC000123</Column_0>
```

And, here's the fist element of the _sourceEntries collection:

```
<Field n="Policy Number" c="1" l="" s="" cd="" m="1805" f="" />
```

I know it's going to be something simple, but I just don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Randy

Comment: Your Console.Write have strange format line Console.WriteLine"Field Name: {0}" with only one argument, but you passing 2... Assuming you want to see both should not it be "Field Name: {0}, value {1}"?

Comment: @EoRaptor13 in _clientXml is the descendat node written row or Row?

Comment: Julian, row, in lower case. 

Alexi, sorry, forgot to add the second argument in Writeline. I had two, but when that didn't work, tried to make it simpler by only writing one. Still no joy.

Thank you for looking at it though.

Comment: Did you define a default namespace (xmlns attribute) at the top of the xml source file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This accomplished what I ultimately needed to do:

```
foreach (var clientField in _clientXml.Descendants("row").Descendants())
    {
        foreach (var acordMapRef in
            from sourceEntry in _clientTemplate.Descendants("SourceEntries").Descendants("Field")
                where (string) clientField.Attribute("n") == (string) sourceEntry.Attribute("n")
                from acordMapRef in _clientTemplate.Descendants("Acord").Descendants("Field")
                where (string) sourceEntry.Attribute("m") == (string) acordMapRef.Attribute("id")
                select acordMapRef)
            {
                clientField.Attribute("n").Value = (string) acordMapRef.Attribute("n");
            }
    }
```

But, it's surely a candidate for ugliest code of the month. One thing I noticed in fooling around is that elements in an XElement tree don't seem to match to XElements in an IEnumerable collection. You might notice in the original code, above, I had an object _sourceEntries. This was a collection derived from _clientTemplate.Descendants("SourcEntries").Descendants("Field"). I would have thought that the two forms were essentially equivalent for my purposes, but apparently not. I'd appreciate somebody commenting on this issue.

Thanks folks!

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I wonder about an impedance mismatch between an XML tree -- that is an XElement with children XElements -- and an IEnumerable<XElement> collection. From what I can understand of the documentation, an IEnumerable collection should have the same extension search functionality as an XML tree. Yet, when I substitute a collection for the "reaching into" the XML file, the query doesn't work. 

I dunno, maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
where (string)sourceField.Attribute("n") == (string)clientField.Attribute("n")
```

To:

```
where sourceField.Attribute("n").Value == clientField.Attribute("n").Value
```

Comment: No joy. But, really my original code pretty much looks just like the various examples in books, blogs, and documentation. There just has to be something funky going on; if only I could figure it out.

Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: Ok, its hard to say without seeing your XML, but I would still do the above, because you aren't comparing the attribute values in your code, you're comparing string representations of the XAttribute class.